# How to import and export .sql into mysql or postgres in docker container

Tags: mysql, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I want to import and export .sql into mysql or postgres in docker container

Answer (score 1):

## Backupdocker

> docker exec -it CONTAINER /usr/bin/mysqldump -u USER -pPASSWORD DATABASE > backup.sql

## Restore backup.sql

> docker exec -i CONTAINER /usr/bin/mysql -u USER -pPASSWORD DATABASE < backup.sql

Answer (score 1):

Similarly for postgres:

dump:

```
docker exec -it CONTAINER /usr/bin/pg_dump -U USER DATABASE > backup.sql
```

load:

```
docker exec -i CONTAINER /usr/bin/psql -U USER DATABASE < backup.sql
```

That is for a single database. If you want to do this for all databases and global objects, use pg_dumpall instead.

For a user with a password, you'll want to set up the password non-interactively (e.g., with PGPASSWORD).